# Javascript call method

Tags: javascript, this

Why the following code will output 1 ?

```js
function func(){
  alert(this)
}
var i = 1;
func.call(i);
```

Comment: `MDN` is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition**

function.prototype.call(this,arg1,arg2,...);

Thus, when you call `func.call`, the first argument you pass in is bound to `this` variable. So in the function `func`, any `this` variable will be replaced with your first argument which is `1`.

**To play further**

You can extend more arguments to `func` and call with further arguments and see what happen:

```
function func(a,b){
    alert(this + a*b);
}

func.call(1,2,3);
```

Recall the definition, the first argument or `func.call` refers to `this` variable of `func`. So you'll end up running

```
alert( 1 + 2*3 );
```

** Ref: ** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

** Even further reading **

`function.prototype.call` has another close sibling which is `function.prototype.apply`. The first argument of both functions refers to `this` variable. The only difference is `function.prototype.apply` accepts arguments of such function in array.

So instead of

```
func.call(1,2,3);
```

You will call it by

```
func.apply(1,[2,3]);
```

Have fun playing with it!

Answer (score 1):

Because the first argument of `call` is the functions `this` value, the syntax is

```
function.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

as noted on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Meaning whatever is passed as the first argument to `call` will be `this` inside the called function

```
function func(){
  alert(this)
}

func.call("test"); // alerts "test"
```

To pass arguments, you pass a `this` value, and then the rest of the arguments would be the arguments passed along to the function

```
function func(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    alert(this); // alerts "this_value"
    alert(arg2); // alerts "kitty"
}

func.call("this_value", "hello", "kitty", "cat");
```

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) works the same way, but takes an array of arguments instead

```
func.apply("this_value", ["hello", "kitty", "cat"]);
```